# unable to download ubuntu-12.04.2-server-amd64.iso

Tags: downloads, iso

I downloaded `ubuntu-12.04.2-server-amd64` a couple of weeks ago with file size 687MB with `md5 hash = af5f788aee1b32c4b2634734309cc9e9`.  Today when I download it is 656MB and It does not install.  I've downloaded via different mirrors and different ISPs but still the same problem.  What's going on?

Comment: What do you get if you download it from here? http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

Comment: what is the hash of the 656MB file?

Comment: I no longer have the 656MB file to run the hash.  Downloaded with link above and its back to 687MB with correct hash.